# Anonymous Authentication principal must be set. Spring 4.x

Tags: spring

We have just updated our previous version from spring 3.x to Spring 4.x.  I've changed my AnonymousAuthenticationFilter bean from this

```
<bean id="anonymousAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
<property name="key" value="foobar"/>
<property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
```

to this

```
<bean id ="anonymousAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
<constructor-arg value="key"/>
<constructor-arg value="#{userAttribute.password}"/>
<constructor-arg value="#{userAttribute.authorities}"/>
```

But now we get a compilation error that reads
Constructor threw exception: nexted exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Anonymous authentication principal must be set.

Any help would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because the new variables you have introduced (password and roles) are not set. The error you got is because **this expression was resolved to null**:

```
<constructor-arg value="#{userAttribute.password}"/>
<constructor-arg value="#{userAttribute.authorities}"/>
```

Define the necessary variables and based on your original `userAttribute` object you have replaced and it will work.